# Incline[d] bench?

Tags: adjectives, writing, etymology

While reading about weight lifting, it's common to bump into mentions of incline benches. There's the "incline bench press" exercise, for example, which is a bench press variation used on an "incline bench."

Why is it called an "incline bench" and not an "incline**d** bench"?

Comment: Perhaps because it is a bench on which one inclines. Perhaps just as a casual or careless shortening.

Comment: It has indeed been called an inclined bench since the 19th century in American and British English. Incline bench doesn't really catch on until the 1980s and then surpasses inclined bench in the number of appearances in print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Incline" is a prefix added to a lot of exercises. You can do an "*incline workout*" which might include *incline bench presses*, or *dumbell incline presses*. The 'incline bench' is a bench for an incline workout.

While the bench itself is at an angle and could be described as "inclined", it isn't taking its name from that. When a compound noun contains a verb conjugated in a particular tense it doesn't really have any bearing on how it is used. One that springs to mind is a "wet suit". It's not always wet!

Comment: So do you mean that the bench takes its name from the exercises that require it in order to be performed?

Comment: @Apollo exactly.

Answer (score 3):

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/incline) has the adjective and the noun entries:

> inclined
> adjective US  /ɪnˈklɑɪnd, ˈɪn·klɑind/
> an inclined roof/roadway/surface

> incline
> noun [ C ]
> US  /ˈɪn·klɑin/
> a slope:
> The road has a steep incline for the next ten miles.

Both can be used to describe a bench.

The noun *incline* used in this way is an attributive noun, which similar to the adjective *inclined* modifies *bench*.

As you have observed, the attributive noun version is more common than the adjective one.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=incline+bench%2Cinclined+bench&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true)